# Защита от частых перезагрузок страницы

Tags: php

Итак. Если например за 1 минуту с одного IP идёт 4 запроса, то мы блокируем доступ к сайту на 15 минут. Реализовать я это пытался на файлах, то есть записываем каждый раз в файл:

ip|timestamp|0

Далее проверять, если последний timestamp меньше, чем 3 секунды, то добавлять

> ip|timestamp|1|ip|timestamp|2|ip|timestamp|3

и т.д. Если превысило 5, то блокируем доступ к сайту на 10 минут например.

Но пришла в голову плохая мысль, ведь пользователей много в онлайне и файл заполнится до такой степени, что всему придёт конец. Сессии и cookie предлагать не стоит, так как запрос со стороннего сервера. Или вовсе моё мнение ошибочно?

Comment: 4 запроса за минуту? Это же смешно. От чего защищаетесь?

Comment: @Zhukov Roman, это к примеру сказал. Мне просто важно, правильно ли строить так защиту или нет?

Comment: Нет, такая защита строится средствами (или модулем) веб-сервера, а не интерпретатора.

Comment: @Zhukov Roman, где можно почитать об этом?

Comment: Для отслеживания частоты доступа используйте уже ведущиеся логи веб-сервера. И лучше использовать такой показатель как N-отказов в минуту (в секунду). И не забудьте про исключения.

Comment: @istem, ответьте мне на вопрос, пожалуйста:

если файл станет большого размера, он будет читаться очень долго?

Comment: Смотря как будете читать. Но если нужно будет вычитывать весь файл, то читаться он будет дольше.

Comment: @KoVadim, 30к обращений в секунду есть... Ещё и это в подарок.

Comment: 30к можно сделать на пхп, но скорее всего не один сервер понадобиться. Что это за проект такой? игра в вконтакте? или 30к в перспективе?

@AlexWindHope
Там у меня комментарии закончились. Я не говорил, что редис сложнее. Более того, я даже его рекомендовал три раза. Откуда "бах и вывод" я не знаю.

А мускул в конце предложил, так как для него проще будет найти документацию и обкатать решение. А при правильном написании кода можно будет относительно просто и на другие средства хранения данных перейти.

Comment: в iptables есть всякие такие штуки, можно даже не дропать пакеты а   отправлять их в "медленный" канал на tc (но это зависит от целей мероприятия)

Comment: @Modal, если grep'ать - то не очень.

Answer (score 6):

А может не изобретать велосипед, а взять готовый и погнуть  немного? Называется велосипед [fail2ban](http://go2linux.garron.me/linux/2011/05/fail2ban-protect-web-server-http-dos-attack-1084.html).

Comment: @KoVadim, круче, когда ты понимаешь и пытаешься разобраться.

Comment: ну тогда разбирайтесь:)

Но как по мне, то на файлах делать защиту - сложновато. Лучше базу использовать. Даже наверное лучше что то в стиле [redis](http://redis.io/). Большой плюс - можно задать время жизни ключей - то есть, возможность разбанить пользователя по истечению какого то периода появляется автоматом.

Comment: @KoVadim, но есть и большой минус, используя базу. Мучать её запросами не хочется, это ещё усугубит ситуацию.

Comment: вы думаете, что на файлах сделаете лучше? не уверен. К тому же, redis хранит по большей части в памяти, что даст хороший прирост скорости. Конечно, можно сделать, используя базу так, что даже cray загнется от нагрузки 10 запросов в час, все в Ваших руках.

Comment: @KoVadim, 1 файл принесет какую-то нагрузку? Оо

Comment: легко. смотря как код написать. Хотя представьте себе, что решили забить туда заведомо все айпишники и хотите по ним постоянно проходить. Даже если будете проверять по 1 млн в секунду, это будет чуть больше часа. Я не призываю так делать, но как пример привел. И самое интересное, что найдутся люди, которые так сделают и даже будут продавать.

Comment: @KoVadim, а какой вариант тогда? Я хочу сам написать, поэтому не предлагайте готовых решений, пожалуйста...

Comment: Я писал - используйте редиску (redis). Как по мне - это очень хорошее решение. Но для начала я бы начал с обычного MySQL. Если в Вашем проекте не 100к обращений в секунду - управиться. Код то не сложный. Сам бы сервер делал в виде REST. Нужен запрос "обращение пользователя" и ответ "пустить/не пустить/позвонить админу". Ну и ещё пару запросов вида "дай список текущих банов", "разбань пользователя такого то". Почему REST? большинство программистов просто уже знает как с ним работать.

Comment: >для начала я бы начал с обычного MySQL

@KoVadim, по вашему, redis сложнее MySQL?..

Comment: @KoVadim, сайт раскрутки для ВК. Где пользователи выполняют задания других пользователей. Активность очень высокая. "Игра ВКонтакте" слишком близко :) Я вообще не хочу для этого дела БД трогать и тот же redis. Хочу изобрести свой велосипед вообщем.

Comment: @KoVadim, + насколько я знаю, сайт падает из-за запросов к БД. А тут тебя будут бесконечно мучать, а ты ещё с БД будешь получать время, когда разбанить. Это вообще. Ддос при ддосе :D Поэтому и файлы нужны. Только размеры огромные не устраивают.

Comment: Кстати, можно же хранить данные в самом ВК, чтобы не париться с нагрузкой на БД: [`storage.set()`](https://vk.com/dev/storage.set) и  [`storage.get()`](https://vk.com/dev/storage.get)

Answer (score 1):

Для nginx модуль [LimitReq](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLimitReqModule), который по дефолту включен при компиляциии.

Для Apache не так просто, [вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131681/how-can-i-implement-rate-limiting-with-apache-requests-per-second). Предлагают  mod_evasive и mod_cband, а также в общем случае mod_limitipconn, mod_bw, mod_bwshare.

Answer (score 1):

Если вЕлик необходим, я тут набросал. Расходы времени и размеров можно сократить, организовав сам файл правильно. К примеру, переводить ip в бинарный вид:

```
function ip2bin($ip)
    {
    $ip = explode('.', $ip);
    return chr($ip[0]).chr($ip[1]).chr($ip[2]).chr($ip[3]);
    }

// и наоборот:
function bin2ip($bin)
    {
    return ord($bin[0]).'.'.ord($bin[1]).'.'.ord($bin[2]).'.'.ord($bin[3]);
    }
```

Тогда точно будешь уверен: данные об IP занимают 4 байта. В идеале и всю остальную инфу тоже нужно хранить так же. Но я для примера сделал так:

```
// понадобится для нормирования чисел в «обычном виде»:
function norm_len($s, $len = 11, $fill = '0')
    {
    if (strlen($s) >= $len)
        return $s;
    else
        {
        $fill = $fill[0];
        return str_repeat($fill, $len - strlen($s)).$s;
        }
    }

$f = fopen('iptest.bin', "w");
$counter = 0;

// заполняем нашу базу случайными значениями:
for ($counter = 0; $counter < 200000; $counter++)
    {
    // случайный IP:
    $ip = rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255);
    // просто, чтоб знать, какой IP найдется — для теста:
    $count = $counter+1;
    $timestamp = time();

    // приводим к нужному виду:
    $ip = ip2bin($ip);
    //$ip = norm_len($ip, 4, ' ');  // 4 байта; приводить не требуется
    $count = norm_len($count, 10, '0'); // 10 байт
    $timestamp = norm_len($timestamp, 11, '0'); // 11 байт

    // теперь мы уверены, что размер каждой записи составляет
    // 4 + 10 + 11 = 25 (байт)

    fwrite($f, $ip.$count.$timestamp, 25);
    }

fclose($f);

die('Filled. Last IP: '.bin2ip($ip));
```

Файлик заполнен. Пробуем искать:

```
$f = fopen('iptest.bin', "r");

$current_ip = '146.115.156.250';
$ip = NULL;

fseek($f, 0);
echo 'Searching for "'. $current_ip .'"...'."\n";

$current_ip = ip2bin($current_ip);  // приводим к бинарному виду

$length = filesize('iptest.bin');
//while (!feof($f))  // не работает почему-то..
while (ftell($f) < $length)
    {
    $ip = fread($f, 4);

    if ($ip === $current_ip)
        {
        echo '+ ' . bin2ip($ip).' <- that`s it!'."\n";
        $count = intval(fread($f, 10));
        $timestamp = intval(fread($f, 11));
        echo '  Timestamp: '. $timestamp .' ('. date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp) .')'."\n";
        echo '  Count: '. $count ."\n";
        //break;  // не будем выходить при первом совпадении
        } else
        {
        //echo '- ' . bin2ip($ip) ."\n";
        fseek($f, 21, SEEK_CUR);  // всегда точно знаем, на сколько нужно сместиться
        }

    }

fclose($f);
```

Функцию `norm_len` нужно доделать еще для отрицательных чисел (ну или учитывать "00000-23464" уже при «распаковке»).

Хранилище изобретено. Чтение файла достаточно быстрое, но все же будет сильно нагружать систему при большом количестве клиентов. Этот метод нужно использовать для выявления злоумышленника, после чего информацию о бане записывать в сессию, чтобы не гонять постоянно винт по этому файлу. Я еще подумаю, как сделать асинхронный поиск по файлу (к примеру, составлять список задач, и производить поиск не чаще 1 раза в 10 секунд, после чего сохранять вердикт в <s>самопальную</s> сессию). Это позволит снизить нагрузку при чтении, но может дать плохишу дополнительные 10 секунд.

Осталось только придумать, какие данные там лучше всего хранить, чтобы выявлять плохишей.

*Мой личный вывод: лучше не трогать похапе и прибегнуть к использованию готовых, более продвинутых решений.*

Answer (score 0):

Imho вариант с базой данных гораздо лучше варианта с файлом. Когда 100 потоков начнут писать в файл, то могут возникать коллизии или блокировки на запись. Никаких группировок и сортировок при работе с файлом не удастся нормально сделать. Когда-нибудь файл вырастет до такой степени, что 
защита сама сайт и положит.

Вообще, смысла "Защищаться от частых перезагрузок страницы" нет. Если пользователь хочет перезагружать - пусть перезагружает. Делайте кеширование, если так нужно. Другое дело - защищать свой контент от неопознанных ботов-воришек.

Т.е. вы можете сделать такую штуку, чтобы поиграться. Но профита она не даст.

Готовое решение уже советовали - fail2ban. Блокировки ip будут на уровне iptables, а не кода приложения. Блокировки на основе лог-файлов сервера.